# Voronoi Diagram Missing Polygons

Tags: java, polygon, voronoi

My problem is a strange one, and I havent seen anything like it while searching for an answer. I have made a Voronoi diagram from Delaunay triangulation, and most of the time it works fine, but it very occasionally, there is a random polygon missing in the middle of the diagram. Here is my code for the Voronoi diagram from the triangulation.

```
public void gon() {
    for(Node n : nodes) { // step through all the nodes which make up the triangulation
        ArrayList<Triangle> centers = new ArrayList<Triangle>();
        for(Triangle t:tri) {
            if((t.ax == n.x && t.ay == n.y)||(t.bx == n.x && t.by == n.y)||(t.cx == n.x && t.cy == n.y)) {
                centers.add(t);
            }
        }
        if(centers.size() != 0) { // as long as there are triangles in the list that will make up a polygon
            ArrayList<Triangle> orderPoly = order(centers);

            int[] x = new int[orderPoly.size()];
            int[] y = new int[orderPoly.size()];

            Cell cell = new Cell(orderPoly.size());

            orderPoly = order(centers);

            for(int i = 0; i < orderPoly.size(); i++) {
                x[i] = orderPoly.get(i).circumCenter.x;
                y[i] = orderPoly.get(i).circumCenter.y;
            }

            cell.x=x;
            cell.y=y;

            cell.check();

            cells.add(cell);
        }
    } 
}
```

The code here goes through the points that make up the triangulation, gets all triangles that use that point, orders the points(code below), and then proceeds to add them to the Voronoi cell class, which contains a polygon for painting purposes, then adds that cell to the cells Arraylist.

```
public ArrayList<Triangle> order(ArrayList<Triangle> centers){

    ArrayList<Triangle> orderPoly = new ArrayList<Triangle>();

    orderPoly.add(centers.get(0));

    Triangle temp = orderPoly.get(0);

    for(Triangle t : centers) {
        for(Triangle p : centers) {
            if(shareSide(p,temp) && !orderPoly.contains(p)) {
                orderPoly.add(p);
                temp = p;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return orderPoly;
}
```

This works for the vast majority of the cells, yet occasionally there is a missing cell. I believe that the cell exists, but is just not being painted because the polygon self intersects. I have done lots of debugging with a seeded random generator and this seems to be the problem. This leads me to believe that there must be a flaw in the generation of my cells. Does anybody have some advice or see anything wrong?

I can post more code for any of my classes if anyone needs.

Comment: To debug this kind of thing, you need to make it completely repeatable. This means using a constant to seed your random number generator. Find a constant that shows the problem (and make sure it shows it every time). Then figure out a conditional break point that will allow you to step through the code that is relevant to the missing item. Good luck!

Comment: I found a seed that didnt work and was debugging based on that. That led me to my conclusion. Thank you